# Can't control Android SearchView focus

Tags: java, android, focus, searchview

I have an activity with `SearchView` the problem I am having is

1- I can't get focus when activity starts. I solved this by using `searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();` from `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. I thought this would be default because there is nothing else in this activity? Is this the right way to solve the problem?

2- The real problem is I am using zxing `IntentIntegrator` and I want to hide the `@+id/coordinator_layout` when I return from scanner and search is in progress.

I start scanner with this code and `onActivityResult()` I start the `AsyncTask`

```
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setCaptureActivity(BarcodeScannerActivity.class);
    integrator.initiateScan();
```

But when I set `R.id.coordinator_layout` visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE inside `AsyncTask`, immediately SearchView gets focus. This happens only after returning from a barcode scanner activity and running `AsyncTask` with following code in `onPreExecute()`

```
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);
    coordinatorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then focus goes to `SearchView` and softkeyboard pops up. Why is this happening?

Below are the layouts I use.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Design.Light"
            android:visibility="gone">
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am inflating this at `onCreateOptionsMenu()` pretty standard `SearchView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_tint_control_normal_24"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

toolbar_main :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Update:

For now I solved the problem by using this in `onPreExecute()`. I am not sure why and how, but I can still get focus on `SearchView` by touching on it even after this... strange...

```
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.setFocusable(false);
    }
```

Comment: Try with `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: @Gotiasits I am not using the support library. But also the issue seems to be related to barcode scanning activity I am running. Perhaps I should collapse the SearchView if I return from barcode scanner?